# i am getting error on windows subsystem

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when I switch to typing with bash on my windows laptop, it returns me an error like the one below, I searched a bit but couldn't find it and I'm very newbie, can you help me?

this error :

```bash
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:347: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:351: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:524: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (8) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:533: Create process not expected to return

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5923#issuecomment-739117772) might help.

One cause of such error is that the default WSL distro is set to `docker` install. In this case you can find which distro is currently a default distro with `wsl -l` command and change it to right one with `wsl -s <distro_name>` command.